# How to read data in cloud storage data using clouds functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to make a cloud function using python, which reads json files containing schemas of tables from a directory in the cloud storage and from these schemas I need to create tables in bigquery.

I had some attempts to access cloud storage, but without success, previously I developed something similar in google colab, reading these schemas from a directory on the drive, but now things seem quite different.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [Streaming data from Cloud Storage into BigQuery using Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/streaming-data-from-cloud-storage-into-bigquery-using-cloud-functions) solution guide of GCP.

If you'd like a different approach you can refer to the download object guide at the [GCP doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#code-samples) to retrieve the data from GCS, see the sample code below.

```
from google.cloud import storage


def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
"""Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
# bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
# source_blob_name = "storage-object-name"
# destination_file_name = "local/path/to/file"

storage_client = storage.Client()

bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

print(
    "Blob {} downloaded to {}.".format(
        source_blob_name, destination_file_name
    )
)
```

Comment: What would that be?
# source_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

Comment: when you have a file in a GCS bucket, the name of the file including any directories would be the "source_blob_name", say you have this file in GCS gs://bucket_name/folder1/photo.jpg - the bucket_name would be "bucket_name" and the source_blob_name would be "folder1/photo.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

You can create Cloud Function and read the download data from the file in Cloud Storage

```
def loader(event, context):
    """Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    try:
        file_name = event['name']
        bucket_name = event['bucket']

        client = storage.Client()

        bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        file_blob = storage.Blob(file_name, bucket)
        data = file_blob.download_as_string().decode()
```

Once you get the data you can create table in BigQuery.